# fill missing values based on the last value

Tags: python, pandas, fillna, ffill

I want to fill missing values based on the last value of every Id

for example , I want this datafarme

```
id value
  1     a
  1   nan
  1   nan
  1     b
  2     c
  2   nan
  2   nan
  2     d
```

to be

```
id value
  1   a
  1   b
  1   b
  1   b
  2   c
  2   d
  2   d
  2   d
```

data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,'a'], [1,np.nan], [1,np.nan],
                            [1,'b'], [2,'c'], [2,np.nan], [2,np.nan],
                            [2,'d']]),
                   columns=['id', 'value'])
```

Comment: Use `df['value'] = df.groupby(['id'])['value'].bfill()`

Comment: df['value']=df['value'].bfill()